# Problema configurando a porta serial em C++ no Linux?

Tags: c++, serial

**Descrição:**

Estou com um problema que é o port de um código em C# para C++ não funcionar por causa da porta serial. Notei também que no dispositivo /dev/ttyS0 estou vendo os mesmos bytes que no C++ e não os que são lidos pelo C#.

O outro lado da comunicação é feito por um microcontrolador em uma UART e apenas as variáveis do *"mode"* deste trecho de código abaixo são configuradas.

**Dúvidas:**

Alguém sabe como seria a configuração da porta serial na API do Termios para ficar idêntica a do Mono?

Ou o que pode ser na minha configuração atual que me faria perder bytes ou parte deles?

Ao abrir em C++, a serial está com a comunicação falhando. Por exemplo, o byte 0xAA que eu deveria receber para iniciar a comunicação não é recebido nunca, mas muitos bytes são recebidos e parece que no lugar estou recebendo 0x15.

Segue o código de abertura que faz a configuração de acordo com o modo e tanto o número da porta, quanto velocidade e as opções de modo estão iguais.

```
int RS232_OpenComport(int comport_number, int baudrate, const char *mode)
{
    int baudr,
        status;

    if ((comport_number>(MAXIMUM_COMPORTS-1)) || (comport_number<0))
    {
        printf("illegal comport number\n");
        return(1);
    }

    switch (baudrate)
    {
        case      50: baudr = B50;
            break;
        case      75: baudr = B75;
            break;
        case     110: baudr = B110;
            break;
        case     134: baudr = B134;
            break;
        case     150: baudr = B150;
            break;
        case     200: baudr = B200;
            break;
        case     300: baudr = B300;
            break;
        case     600: baudr = B600;
            break;
        case    1200: baudr = B1200;
            break;
        case    1800: baudr = B1800;
            break;
        case    2400: baudr = B2400;
            break;
        case    4800: baudr = B4800;
            break;
        case    9600: baudr = B9600;
            break;
        case   19200: baudr = B19200;
            break;
        case   38400: baudr = B38400;
            break;
        case   57600: baudr = B57600;
            break;
        case  115200: baudr = B115200;
            break;
        case  230400: baudr = B230400;
            break;
        case  460800: baudr = B460800;
            break;
        case  500000: baudr = B500000;
            break;
        case  576000: baudr = B576000;
            break;
        case  921600: baudr = B921600;
            break;
        case 1000000: baudr = B1000000;
            break;
        case 1152000: baudr = B1152000;
            break;
        case 1500000: baudr = B1500000;
            break;
        case 2000000: baudr = B2000000;
            break;
        case 2500000: baudr = B2500000;
            break;
        case 3000000: baudr = B3000000;
            break;
        case 3500000: baudr = B3500000;
            break;
        case 4000000: baudr = B4000000;
            break;
        default: printf("invalid baudrate\n");
            return(1);
            break;
    }

    int cbits = CS8,
        cpar = 0,
        ipar = IGNPAR,
        bstop = 0;

    if (strlen(mode) != 3)
    {
        printf("invalid mode \"%s\"\n", mode);
        return(1);
    }

    switch (mode[0])
    {
        case '8': cbits = CS8;
            break;
        case '7': cbits = CS7;
            break;
        case '6': cbits = CS6;
            break;
        case '5': cbits = CS5;
            break;
        default: printf("invalid number of data-bits '%c'\n", mode[0]);
            return(1);
            break;
    }

    switch (mode[1])
    {
        case 'N':
        case 'n': cpar = 0;
            ipar = IGNPAR;
            break;
        case 'E':
        case 'e': cpar = PARENB;
            ipar = INPCK;
            break;
        case 'O':
        case 'o': cpar = (PARENB | PARODD);
            ipar = INPCK;
            break;
        default: printf("invalid parity '%c'\n", mode[1]);
            return(1);
            break;
    }

    switch (mode[2])
    {
        case '1': bstop = 0;
            break;
        case '2': bstop = CSTOPB;
            break;
        default: printf("invalid number of stop bits '%c'\n", mode[2]);
            return(1);
            break;
    }

    /*
    http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/termios.h.html

    http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html
    */

    Cport[comport_number] = open(comports[comport_number], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (Cport[comport_number] == -1)
    {
        perror("unable to open comport ");
        return(1);
    }

    /* lock access so that another process can't also use the port */
    if (flock(Cport[comport_number], LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) != 0)
    {
        close(Cport[comport_number]);
        perror("Another process has locked the comport.");
        return(1);
    }

    error = tcgetattr(Cport[comport_number], old_port_settings + comport_number);
    if (error == -1)
    {
        close(Cport[comport_number]);
        perror("unable to read portsettings ");
        return(1);
    }
    memset(&new_port_settings, 0, sizeof(new_port_settings));  /* clear the new struct */

    new_port_settings.c_cflag = cbits | cpar | bstop | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    new_port_settings.c_iflag = ipar;
    new_port_settings.c_oflag = 0;
    new_port_settings.c_lflag = 0;
    new_port_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;      /* block untill n bytes are received */
    new_port_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;     /* block untill a timer expires (n * 100 mSec.) */

    cfsetispeed(&new_port_settings, baudr);
    cfsetospeed(&new_port_settings, baudr);

    error = tcsetattr(Cport[comport_number], TCSANOW, &new_port_settings);
    if (error == -1)
    {
        close(Cport[comport_number]);
        perror("unable to adjust portsettings ");
        return(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(Cport[comport_number], TIOCMGET, &status) == -1)
    {
        perror("unable to get portstatus");
        return(1);
    }

    status |= TIOCM_DTR;    /* turn on DTR */
    status |= TIOCM_RTS;    /* turn on RTS */

    if (ioctl(Cport[comport_number], TIOCMSET, &status) == -1)
    {
        perror("unable to set portstatus");
        return(1);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei encontrando o problema em uma configuração do device tree blob do linux, que tinha um pino erradamente configurado para o meu hardware.